# Why is the saved scroll position affected by a shrinking navbar on page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but I couldn't find one that answers this in my case. I am using an `IntersectionObserver` to trigger a navbar style (to shrink it). The navbar has the `sticky-top` class, with the viewport as the root (implicit).

The subtle issue is, on reloading the page, the scroll position is remembered, but it seems to adjust as the navbar shrinks. This results in a gradual "ratcheting up" of the page on subsequent reloads. I don't expect users to continuously reload the page, but I wanted to thoroughly understand what is going on, and why this is occurring.

[Here is a jsfiddle which demonstrate the issue.](https://jsfiddle.net/r9n0txm4/)

To see the issue, scroll the content frame down until the navbar shrinks, and then right click the frame to reload just that frame (since reloading the whole jsfiddle page will reset everything, including the scroll position).

One theory I have is that the scroll position is being restored prior to the `position: sticky;` style becoming effectively `position: fixed;`, thus the height of the navbar is throwing off the scroll position.

However, the scroll position seems to shift only by a small amount. This leads me to believe that the browser is smart enough to account for the sticky element being removed from the page flow, and accounts for the difference, but it cannot know ahead of time that the element will shrink. This still confuses me though, since the size of the navbar after it is removed from the flow of the page should not be relevant to the restored scroll position.

I have a hunch that there is some kind of race condition causing this, where the relevant events are the scroll restore, the IntersectionObserver event on the trigger element, and the application of the skinny navbar styles. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Maybe because the navbar elements are links and we are getting redirected to the same page. Try it with something like `document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault()));` to prevent links to work

Comment: @Zyigh I'm not really sure what you mean. The issue isn't in clicking the navbar links, but in purposely reloading the page. When scrolled down to where the navbar shrinks, reloading restores the scroll position slightly up the page each time.